# how to pull multiple data from Firebase and setState simultaneously

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Fire.shared.getname(net_result =>
      this.setState({net:sunet_result}));
      Fire.shared.getname(name_result =>
        this.setState({name:name_result}));
        Fire.shared.getprofile(profile_result =>
          this.setState({profile:profile_result}));
    console.log(this.state.name)
  }
```

Right now in the above code, when I console.log(this.state.name), it prints a name value that is not updated by the data pulled from Firebase due to the "this.setState({name:name_result}));" line being after another this.state. How do I bypass this "multiple this.setstate" debacle?

Comment: You can use `async/await` to save each Firebase value in a variable, then call `setState` once at the end to set them all. Also, `setState` is asynchronous, so you can't `console.log` the state on the next line and expect it to have changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a single `setState` in the inner callback:

```
Fire.shared.getname(net_result =>
  Fire.shared.getname(name_result =>
    Fire.shared.getprofile(profile_result => {
      this.setState({net:sunet_result, name:name_result, profile:profile_result})
    });
```